# Lazy loaded One to One optional relationship not using where clause on select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a lazy loaded one to one relationship. When I call select on it and try to filter where the optional is not null, it doesn't get generate the where clause for the is not null. It pulls in all users, regardless of whether they have an Employment or not.

My user:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Employment Employment { get; set; }
}
```

My Employment

```
public class Employment
{
    [InverseProperty("Employment")]
    public User User { get; set;  }
}
```

My query

```
await (from user in _dataContext.Users
       where user.Employment != null
       select user).ToListAsync()
```

This way doesn't work either:

```
await _dataContext.Users
                  .Include(t => t.Employment)
                  .Where(t => t.Employment != null)
                  .ToListAsync();
```

In the sql it generates, the where clause just doesn't get generated.

In Fluent I am setting:

```
b.HasOne(u => u.Employment)
 .WithOne(t => t.User)
 .IsRequired(false);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In your Fluent, try: `Entity<User>().HasOptional(u => u.Employment).WithRequired(e => e.User);` and remove the `InverseProperty` attribute: I don't think you need it if you're using Fluent. Also, confirm from your database that the field is actually nullable: I suspect it's not, and that's why the SQL generator is ignoring your `where`.

Comment: I already have the Fluent setting in there. And it is optional. The Employment has the Userid

Comment: Do you have a foreign key? One to one is only possible with foreign key

Comment: @abc Can you show the actual SQL that *is* generated?

Comment: I solved it by doing the inverse

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I needed by doing the inverse:

```
await _dataContext.Employment
                  .Include(t => t.User)
                  .Select(t => t.User)
                  .Include(t => t.Employment)
                  .ToListAsync();
```

although it still doesn't make sense that the Where clause would just be ignored.